# Show that $\int_X gdν=\int_X gfdμ$ for all $g∈L_1(ν).$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $μ$ and $ν$ be finite (positive) measures on a measurable space $(X, M),$ and suppose that
$ν(E)=\int_E fdμ$, for all $E∈M,$ $E$
where $f$ is some function in $L_1(μ).$ Show that
$\int_X gdν=\int_X gfdμ$ for all $g∈L_1(ν).$

This is a past qual problem.

I can do this problem for $g$ simple but not in general?  Any suggestions for the last step?  Thanks

Comment: Simple functions are dense in $L^{p}(\mu)$, when $(X,M,\mu)$ is a ($\sigma$-)finite measure space.

Answer (score 3):

For each nonnegative measurable function $g$, there is a sequence of simple functions $g_n \uparrow g$.  Now use monotone convergence twice.  For the general case, write $g = g^+ - g^-$.

Comment: It worth to mention here that by Radon–Nikodym theorem $f$ is nonnegative $\mu$-a.e. and then the monotone convergence theorems works!

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi: You don't even need the Radon-Nikodym theorem for that.  Simply apply the definition of $\nu$ with $E = \{ f < 0 \}$.

Comment: yeah! The good point is that I do learn or review lots of tricks and ideas from the given proofs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, it is Radon-Nikodym theorem: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem

In fact, here $f = \frac{{\rm d}\nu}{{\rm d}\mu}$, and by property  4 in the link the claim is straightforward. Note that the proof of properties are also mentioned there.

Comment: How do you apply this to OP's question? The $f$ satisfying $\nu(E)=\int_E f \mathop{d\mu}$ is already given.

Comment: I have edited the answer, BTW the answer of Nate Eldredge is totally correct!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!